# Using Node.js I get, "Error: EISDIR, read"

Tags: node.js

When ever I try to open a file I get,

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: EISDIR, read
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

This error is simple,

```
cd /tmp
mkdir dir
node -e "var fs = require('fs'); fs.createReadStream( 'dir' );"
```

**EISDIR** means that the target of the operation is a directory in reality but that the expected filetype of the target is something *other* than a directory.

Comment: You can select your own answer as the proper answer by the way, that's allowed by the rules. :)

Comment: It makes me wait. As if I answered my own question wrongly and I need time to think about it. Blame Jeff.

Answer (score 16):

`EISDIR` error occurs when you try to open a file, but the path given is a directory.

You can fix this by checking if is it directory-

```js
if (fs.lstatSync(filePath).isDirectory()) {
  return;
}
```

For more reference see docs [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats).

Answer (score 4):

Just came across this error and in my case it was due having used `bower link` previously to link to local sources which then creates a symlink in the directory.
Once I've `bower unlink`ed all the components, it worked again as expected.

Hope this might help someone.

Answer (score 1):

You might get lucky checking for such error codes by running something like:

```
grep EISDIR -r /usr/include
```

When I do this, I get a line that says:

```
/usr/include/uv.h:  XX(EISDIR, "illegal operation on a directory")
```