# Node.js Error: EISDIR, open Error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to copy one folder to another using node.js here is folder path:-

`D:\node\files\11\j1_1\j1_2\j1_3`
I want to copy folder j1_3 to path
`D:\node\files\11\j1_1\`

here is my code:-

```
var source = fs.createReadStream(old);
var dest = fs.createWriteStream(newp);
source.pipe(dest);
source.on('end', function () { /* copied */ });
source.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log("hi");
    /* error */
});
```

but I am getting this error:-

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
 Error: EISDIR, open 'D:\node\files\11\j1_1'
```

I have also try fs.rename function but getting same error.

Comment: one additional clarification. The error you are getting at the writestream is because  fs does not automatically append the new filename to the dest. Which cp and ncp do, so to fix the issue you could have also added the new filename to the dest instead of using ncp / cp. Resulting in: newp + path.basename(old);

Comment: @Bram thanks for information :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: **EISDIR** means "error! target is a dir"(i guess), [about the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417118/using-node-js-i-get-error-eisdir-read)

Second: [ncp](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ncp) is what you need i guess