# node.js Error: EISDIR, open

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I tried to uplaod file and move to new directory already exists.
follow [Writing files in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js) but I got the error:
`Error: EISDIR, open '/Users/name/Sites/project/app/assets/images/UploadTemporary/'
    at Error (native)`

and I found [Using Node.js I get, "Error: EISDIR, read"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417118/using-node-js-i-get-error-eisdir-read) and [Node.js Error: EISDIR, open Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951269/node-js-error-eisdir-open-error) similar error message,  my `UploadTemporary` folder already exists do I mess something wrong?
I don't get it, if its not a directory what else can be?

```
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var appDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);

...
var sourceFile = req.files.file[0].path;
var destinationFile = appDir + '/assets/images/UploadTemporary/';

var source = fs.createReadStream(sourceFile);
var destination = fs.createWriteStream(destinationFile);

source.pipe(destination);
source.on('end', function () {
  fs.unlinkSync(sourceFile);
});
```

Comment: You need to give the actual filename in the `destinationFile`

Comment: you mean something like this `var destinationFile = appDir+'/assets/images/UploadTemporary/'+newfilename`

Comment: Exactly. I think you are thinking that giving just the directory name will create a file with the source file name, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you are writing a file to a specific directory, you need to give the actual destination file name as well. Unlike `cp` command, the destination filename will not be inferred by `fs` module.

In your case, you are trying to write to a directory, instead of a file. That is why you are getting `EISDIR` error. To fix this, as you mentioned in the comments,

```
var destinationFile = appDir + '/assets/images/UploadTemporary/' + newfilename;
```

include the file name as well.