# Node.JS readFileSync() function

Tags: javascript, node.js

index.js

```
var server = require("./server");
var router = require("./router");

server.start(router.route);
```

server.js

```
//Script to start a server

var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var fs = require("fs");

function start(route) {
    function onRequest(request, response) {

        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

        route(pathname, response, fs);

    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

router.js

```
function route(pathname, response, fs) {

    var regex = new RegExp('^/view/?$');

    var directpath = "D:/nodejs/file_upload" + pathname;

    var voo = fs.readFileSync(directpath);

    if(regex.test(pathname)){

        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);
        response.end(voo);

    } else{

        response.writeHead(404);
        response.end("<br/>404, file not found");

    }
}

exports.route = route;
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Hello My friend </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to store the file path in a variable and then feed it ti readFileSync() function, but this gives me fllowing error in the console.

```
Error: EISDIR, illegal operation on a directory
    at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:487:19)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:326:28)
    at route (D:\nodejs\file_upload\router.js:7:15)
    at Server.onRequest (D:\nodejs\file_upload\server.js:15:6)
    at Server.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2108:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:121:23
)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1966:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:527:27)
```

but if I enter the path "D:/nodejs/file_upload/view/index.html" in the function directly then it shows me the page in the browser.

I stored the index.html file in the view folder

Comment: Maybe try `fs.readdir()` and loop through the array it hands back?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Node.js I get, "Error: EISDIR, read"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417118/using-node-js-i-get-error-eisdir-read)

Comment: Most likely, you're trying to read `D:/nodejs/file_upload/view` instead of `D:/nodejs/file_upload/view/index.html`.

Comment: If you want to serve static files, consider using some static module like [st](https://github.com/isaacs/st) or [serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`EISDIR` error occurs when you try to open a file, but the path given is a directory. See related question and answer: [Using Node.js I get, "Error: EISDIR, read"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417118/using-node-js-i-get-error-eisdir-read).

To debug this I would log to console the variable `directpath` and I would assume that it is pointing to a directory, not a file. Correctly setting this variable to the intended path should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `fs.lstatSync(file).isFile()` to filter files from folders. Maybe you can use it as well?