# Upload files to a specific folder in the bucket with AWS SDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm uploading images to AWS S3 with the developer toolkit for node:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const s3Bucket = process.env.S3_BUCKET;
    const s3 = new aws.S3({
      signatureVersion: 'v4',
      region: process.env.S3_REGION,
      accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    });

    const s3Params = {
      Bucket: s3Bucket,
      Key: filename,
      Expires: 60,
      ContentType: filetype,
      ACL: 'public-read',
    };
```

This works but how can I make image be uploaded to a specific folder in the bucket?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Amazon S3 is a flat storage system that does not actually use folders.

Rather, the Key (filename) includes the **full path** of the object, eg:

```
folder1/folder2/foo.txt
```

The Amazon S3 management console does show bucket contents within folders, but they are an artificial construct (called *common prefixes*) to make it easier for us humans to understand.

So, if you want to upload to a particular folder, just **include the full path in the Key** and it will work (or, more accurately, *pretend to work!*).

Fun fact: You can copy to folder that doesn't exist, and the folder will be 'created' for you. Then, if you delete the object, the folder will be 'deleted', because it never actually existed!

Answer (score 18):

you can write key as **FULL PATH**

```
const uploadToS3Bucket = (image, filePath) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let s3 = new AWS.S3({
      accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_KEY,
      region: process.env.S3_REGION,
    });

    const bucketName = process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME;

    let bucketPath = filePath;

    let params = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: bucketPath,
      Body: image,
    };
    s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
};
```

```
await uploadToS3Bucket(imageFile,"folder1/folder2/image1.png");
```

Answer (score 3):

AWS S3 does not have the folder structure. it shows like folder inside S3 bucket but that is Key structure.
I used the copy command in one of my work. copying file in S3 bucket folder.

aws s3 cp myapp.zip s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/FolderName/FileName

Example

aws s3 cp myapp.zip s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/MyFolder/MyFileName

No need to create any folder in AWS S3 bucket it will create the specific folder if it does not exists

The above code is copying myapp.zip file inside the folder - MyFolder of S3 bucket with the file name MyFileName

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we have not the folder object in S3 and all about the key name. When you put the folder likes in your key name for example "folder/myfile.txt," you can see that as a folder on the S3 browser.

The similar question:
https://serverfault.com/questions/435827/what-is-the-difference-between-buckets-and-folders-in-amazon-s3

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the full path in the key value.

```
<?php
require 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials('XXXXX', 'YYYYY');
 
// Instantiate an Amazon S3 client.
$s3Client = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-east-1',
    'credentials' => $credentials
]);
 
 
$bucket = 'my-storage';
$file_Path = 'product_nov2023.jpg';
$key = 'artworkpic/'.basename($file_Path);   // Give full folder path here
 
// Upload a publicly accessible file. The file size and type are determined by the SDK.
try {
    $result = $s3Client->putObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $key,
        'Body'   => fopen($file_Path, 'r'),
        'ACL'    => 'public-read' // make file 'public'
    ]);
    echo "Image uploaded successfully. Image path is: ". $result->get('ObjectURL');
} catch (Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file.\n";
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Note from my expirience - if you will pass url starting with slash "/path/to/file.txt" then amazon will just upload file to root directory without nested folders. If pass path without / "path/to/file.txt" then amazon will create nested directories.

Answer (score 0):

Try This working well.

```
require 'aws-sdk-s3'


folder_path = '/local/folder_path'

Dir.foreach(folder_path) do |xml_file|
  next if xml_file == '.' || xml_file == '..'
  file_path = "folder_path/#{xml_file}"
  object_key = xml_file

  s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
    region: 'us-east-1',
    access_key_id: '',
    secret_access_key: ''
    )
    bucket = s3.bucket(bucket_name)

    obj = bucket.object(object_key)
    obj.upload_file(file_path)

    puts "File uploaded successfully!"

 end
```