# How to Upload file in a directory to minIO bucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, amazon-s3, minio

Hello everyone i have bucket in minio server and bucket name is 'geoxing' and geoxing have directory img/site. i want to upload picture in site directry using nodejs. below is code and i am getting error Invalid bucket name: geoxing/img/site. how can i solve this error. thanks

```
savefile() {
    const filePath = 'D://repositories//uploads//geoxing//site//b57e46b4bcf879839b7074782sitePic.jpg';
const bucketname = 'geoxing/img/site'
    var metaData = {
      'Content-Type': 'image/jpg',
      'Content-Language': 123,
      'X-Amz-Meta-Testing': 1234,
      example: 5678,
    };
    this.minioClient.fPutObject(
      bucketname,
      'b57e46b4bcf879839b7074782sitePic.jpg',
      filePath,
      metaData,
      function (err, objInfo) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        return console.log('Success', objInfo.etag);
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: The bucket would be `geoxing`, the key would be `img/site/b57e46b4bcf879839b7074782sitePic.jpg`.

Comment: wow, thank you. the problem is solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Amazon S3 and Minio:

- **Bucket** should just be the name of the bucket (eg `geoxing`)
- **Key** should include the *full path* as well as the filename (eg `img/site/b57e46b4bcf879839b7074782sitePic.jpg`)

Amazon S3 and Minio do not have 'folders' or 'directories' but they emulate directories by including the path name in the `Key`. Folders do not need to be created prior to uploading to a folder -- they just magically appear when files are stored in that 'path'.

Comment: Hi sir, i want to upload local directry to minio that contains multiple files. like gexoing is folder and i want to upload whole folder by using nodejs. how can i do it

Comment: @umer The API calls only allow **one** file to be uploaded at a time. Therefore, the code would need to **loop** through all the files, uploading each one individually. This might be helpful: [Upload entire directory tree to S3 using AWS sdk in node js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27670051/174777)

Comment: Yes, this is really helpful. i solve the problem. thanks