# Node: Using fs.readFile getting Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, fs

I have a problem getting `fs.readFile` to return a css file. I've already read in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883775/node-js-readfilesync-function) that `EISDIR error` occurs when you try to open a file, but the path given is a directory. But I've checked several times and the `console.log` inside the `getCss` function is logging the right path with the correct filename and `.css` extension. What's the issue? Thanks in advance!

```
// Path to MUI css
muiCssFile = path.join(muiDistFolder, 'css', 'mui.css'),  


// Read css files
function getCss(callback) {
  console.log('MUI CSS file path in getCss() :: ', muiCssFile);
  // Code fails here.... 
  fs.readFile(muiCssFile, 'utf8', function (err, css) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }
    fs.readFile(styleFile, function (error, customCss) {
      if (error) return callback(error);
      callback(null, css + customCss);
    });
  });
```

}

Comment: On which line are you getting the error, you have two calls to `readFile`

Comment: The very first one.

Comment: Try navigating to the path that is printed in the console. If that works, then try changing the name of the file. This will probably give some clue.

Comment: Ok. This was an oversight on my part. Turns out it was actually the second fs.readFile that was throwing the error. When I checked the path variable it was indeed missing it's extension so readFile thought it was a folder! Lesson learned. Thanks for the help debugging it!

Answer (score 9):

Ok, just for anyone stumbling across this error I thought it would help to provide a short answer to my question. The error is most likely caused by one or more of the paths you are trying to use `fs.readFile` on ending on a directory path and **NOT** a file.

In my specific case above, the error was actually occurring on the second `fs.readFile` call so be sure to check **ALL** paths first and ensure that they do in fact lead to files to uncover the problem path. Hope that helps someone save some time getting past this error.