# WARN tar EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-link

I am trying to publish a module to npm registry. Before publishing I tried `npm link` command to install it as a local dependency.

Running the command started throwing errors similar to following.

> WARN tar EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open
> '/[[path_to_project]]/node_modules/.staging/@babel/plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator-049e5354/lib'
>
> npm WARN rm not removing /[[path_to_project]]/node_modules/.bin/semver
> as it wasn't installed by /[[path_to_project]]/node_modules/semver
>
> test-pkg@1.0.0 requires a peer of react@16.7.0 but none
> is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN
> test-pkg@1.0.0 requires a peer of react-dom@16.7.0 but
> none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm
> WARN test-pkg@1.0.0 No description

I spent hours trying to fix this but no luck yet. I went through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44631383/npm-command-error-eisdir-illegal-operation-on-a-directory-read) and removed .npmrc but that did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `.npmrc`, deleting and reinstalling `node_modules` did not work for me.

I solved this problem by setting --production flag as `npm link --production"` And also `yarn link` worked without any issue. Hope this helps if someone is having the same problem.