# Backup script writen in node.js for AWS S3 make synchronous to backup millions of files

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Many search on google, stackoverflow and bing I have made but I have no answer find for my problem.

How can I make my backup script to run synchronous. I have the problem with too many files in the folder and subfolders stop the script as result of too many open files (fs.createReadStream).

I hope somebody can help me.
Thank you.
Greetings Sven

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
        , s3 = new AWS.S3()
        , fs = require('fs')
        , wrench = require('wrench')
        , util = require('util')

        var smadir = "/Users/myuser/myfolder"
          , smafiles = wrench.readdirSyncRecursive(smadir)

          smafiles.forEach (function (file) {
             var params = {Bucket: 'mybucked', Key: file, Body: fs.createReadStream(smadir + '/' + file)};
             var options = {partSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, queueSize: 1};
             s3.upload(params, options, function(err, data) {
               console.log(err, data);
             })
          })
```

Comment: [async.eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Answer (score 2):

You can manually write code that controls how many are uploading at once like this:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
    , s3 = new AWS.S3()
    , fs = require('fs')
    , wrench = require('wrench')
    , util = require('util')

var smadir = "/Users/myuser/myfolder"
    , smafiles = wrench.readdirSyncRecursive(smadir);

var index = 0, maxAtOnce = 10;

function uploadNext() {
    if (index >= smafiles.length) return;
    var file = smafiles[index++];
    var params = {Bucket: 'mybucked', Key: file, Body: fs.createReadStream(smadir + '/' + file)};
    var options = {partSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, queueSize: 1};
    s3.upload(params, options, function(err, data) {
        console.log(err, data);
        // need to decide what to do here if an error occurred

        // since one just finished, launch another one
        uploadNext();
    });
}

// now launch the initial set
for (var i = 0; i < maxAtOnce; i++) {
    uploadNext();
}
```

Or, you can use a library like Async or Bluebird that has functions to manage the max number of parallel operations in flight at the same time.

For the Async library, you could use the `.eachLimit()` method which iterates an array, but limits the max number of operations in flight at the same time.

For the Bluebird promise library, you could use `Promise.map()` and specify the concurrency option to control the max number of operations in flight at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your example. When I the Script run in a directory with very many files I get following error:

  myfile.js events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
  Error: EISDIR, read
    at Error (native)

How I can fix this?

Comment: @sm_a - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417118/using-node-js-i-get-error-eisdir-read.  It sounds like you're trying to open a directory for reading - probably in the wrench code.

Comment: @sm_a - In looking at the wrench code, it looks to me like `readdirSyncRecursive()` returns sub-directory names too,so you are likely calling `fs.createReadStream(smadir + '/' + file)` on a sub-directory which will return EISDIR.  You will have to check to see if it's a directory before attempting to read it.  This seems like a goof in the wrench library since the usual point of a recursive listing is to get all the files and to not have to check each one to see if it's a directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have complete the solution. Here my code. Greetings Sven

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
    , s3 = new AWS.S3()
    , fs = require('fs')
    , wrench = require('wrench')
    , util = require('util')

var smadir = "/home/user/folder"
  , smas3rootdir = "destination_folder"
  , smafiles = wrench.readdirSyncRecursive(smadir)

var index = 0, maxAtOnce = 1;

function uploadNext() {
    if (index >= smafiles.length) return;
    var file = smafiles[index++];
    var smafoldertocheck = smadir + '/' + file
    var smaprepare = fs.statSync(smafoldertocheck).isDirectory()

    if (!smaprepare) {
        var params = {Bucket: 'mybucked', Key: smas3rootdir + '/' + file, Body: fs.createReadStream(smadir + '/' + file)};
        var options = {partSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, queueSize: 1};
        s3.upload(params, options, function(err, data) {
            console.log(err, data);
            // need to decide what to do here if an error occurred

            // since one just finished, launch another one
            uploadNext();
        })
    } else {
        uploadNext();
    }
}

// now launch the initial set
for (var i = 0; i < maxAtOnce; i++) {
    uploadNext();
}
```