# Ember.js Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-cli

When creating a fresh ember project, I receive an error. I have tried everything listed [here.](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/1694) Yet nothing seems to work.

I am new to ember although I have experience with Angular.js and some jQuery. With this project I am trying to complete a tutorial, but I can't seem to get it to even run.

Git Bash output:

```
$npm -v
3.8.3

$ember -v
ember-cli: 2.4.3
node: 5.10.1
os: win32 x64


user@computername MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub
$ ember new EISDIR-SUCKS
installing app
  create .bowerrc
  create .editorconfig
  create .ember-cli
  create .jshintrc
  create .travis.yml
  create .watchmanconfig
  create README.md
  create app\app.js
  create app\components\.gitkeep
  create app\controllers\.gitkeep
  create app\helpers\.gitkeep
  create app\index.html
  create app\models\.gitkeep
  create app\resolver.js
  create app\router.js
  create app\routes\.gitkeep
  create app\styles\app.css
  create app\templates\application.hbs
  create app\templates\components\.gitkeep
  create bower.json
  create config\environment.js
  create ember-cli-build.js
  create .gitignore
  create package.json
  create public\crossdomain.xml
  create public\robots.txt
  create testem.js
  create tests\.jshintrc
  create tests\helpers\destroy-app.js
  create tests\helpers\module-for-acceptance.js
  create tests\helpers\resolver.js
  create tests\helpers\start-app.js
  create tests\index.html
  create tests\integration\.gitkeep
  create tests\test-helper.js
  create tests\unit\.gitkeep
  create vendor\.gitkeep
Successfully initialized git.
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Installed browser packages via Bower.

user@computername MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub
$ cd EISDIR-SUCKS/

user@computername MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub/EISDIR-SUCKS (master)
$ ember serve

Running without elevated rights. Running Ember CLI "as Administrator" increases performance significantly.
See ember-cli.com/user-guide/#windows for details.

Livereload server on http://localhost:49157
Serving on http://localhost:4200/
The Broccoli Plugin: [Funnel: Funnel (config)] failed with:
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:651:19)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:472:24)
    at symlinkWindows (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EISDIR-SUCKS\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\symlink-or-copy\index.js:99:53)
    at Function.symlinkOrCopySync [as sync] (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EISDIR-SUCKS\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\symlink-or-copy\index.js:53:5)
    at Funnel._copy (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EISDIR-SUCKS\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-funnel\index.js:398:19)
    at Funnel.build (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EISDIR-SUCKS\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-funnel\index.js:167:12)
    at C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EISDIR-SUCKS\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\read_compat.js:61:34
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EISDIR-SUCKS\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1036:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EISDIR-SUCKS\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1048:17)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at:
    at Funnel.Plugin (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EISDIR-SUCKS\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\index.js:7:31)
    at new Funnel (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EISDIR-SUCKS\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-funnel\index.js:44:10)
    at EmberApp._configTree (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EISDIR-SUCKS\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:977:28)
    at EmberApp.index (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EISDIR-SUCKS\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:623:40)
    at EmberApp.toArray (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EISDIR-SUCKS\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:1563:10)
    at EmberApp.toTree (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EISDIR-SUCKS\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:1586:30)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EISDIR-SUCKS\ember-cli-build.js:23:14)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.setupBroccoliBuilder (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EISDIR-SUCKS\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:55:19)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.init (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EISDIR-SUCKS\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:89:10)
    at new Class (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EISDIR-SUCKS\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\core-object\core-object.js:18:12)
```

Comment: Looks like an issue with the Broccoli plugin.  Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417118/using-node-js-i-get-error-eisdir-read for info about the EISDIR error.  May want to open an issue with the creators of the broccoli plugin or search there for the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was encountering this issue this evening. I solved it on a hunch by running `ember serve` as an Administrator/from an elevated command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered something similar with angular-cli:

```
ng serve
```

resulting in a Broccoli Funnel error:

```
EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, symlink
```

It turned out to be caused by the fact I'm using a TrueCrypt mounted drive for my code. It's a normal Windows drive in every other aspect, but apparently it operates differently for this nodejs symbolic link stuff.