# ng cli generate component with module broken

Tags: module, components, angular-cli, angular

I'm using the ng cli for the first time. I'm trying to make a new module ('foo') and a new component ('bar') under the foo module. Though, how I think I'm supposed to do it in ng cli doesn't seem to work:

```
mbp:my-new-app chris$ ng g m foo
installing module
create src/app/foo/foo.module.ts

mbp:my-new-app chris$ ng g c bar -m foo
installing component
create src/app/bar/bar.component.scss
create src/app/bar/bar.component.html
create src/app/bar/bar.component.spec.ts
create src/app/bar/bar.component.ts

EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:732:19)
at tryReadSync (fs.js:487:20)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:535:19)
at Class.afterInstall (/Users/chris/code/my-new-app/node_modules/@angular/cli/blueprints/component/index.js:209:34)
at tryCatch (/Users/chris/code/my-new-app/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:539:12)
at invokeCallback (/Users/chris/code/my-new-app/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:554:13)
at publish (/Users/chris/code/my-new-app/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:522:7)
at flush (/Users/chris/code/my-new-app/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2414:5)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
```

ng cli version:

```
mbp:my-new-app chris$ ng version
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
node: 6.10.1
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 4.0.1
@angular/compiler: 4.0.1
@angular/core: 4.0.1
@angular/forms: 4.0.1
@angular/http: 4.0.1
@angular/platform-browser: 4.0.1
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.0.1
@angular/router: 4.0.1
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.0.1
```

Am I doing using this wrong? I haven't found documentation specifically on this feature.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of running

```
ng g c bar -m foo
```

try to run (without -m)

```
ng g c foo/bar
```

if you want to reference a module, which should export/import your new component, you should provide a relative path to this module, like:

```
ng g c bar -m foo/foo.module
```

in this case *bar* component will be imported/exported by *foo.module*, but located under *src/app*.

*EASDIR* error occurred because you provided a directory (*foo*) instead of file (*foo/foo.module*)

as answered for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417118/using-node-js-i-get-error-eisdir-read#20417119):

> EISDIR means that the target of the operation is a directory in reality but that the expected filetype of the target is something other than a directory.