# Update to Grunt causes "Use of const in strict mode" error

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I did some things on our build server, which resulted in Grunt getting updated (oops), and it is now stuck using a new version of grunt-legacy-log-utils, which produces the following:

```
K:\_work\4\s\Web\node_modules\grunt\node_modules\grunt-legacy-log\node_modules\grunt-legacy-log-utils\node_modules\chalk\index.js:2
const escapeStringRegexp = require('escape-string-regexp');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
```

I have tried manually pulling in an older version globally, as well as specifically adding `grunt-legacy-log-utils` to the project's package.json file, but it still pulls down the latest version when running `npm install` during the build.

Is there any way to get around this?  Other similar questions on here say I need a new version of Node, but if I do that my build breaks elsewhere (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687945/build-failing-on-npm-install-typings)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We encountered this issue as well.  Turns out our build agents started using grunt@1.0.3 node_modules/grunt (not sure how or why, it looks like this update to grunt happened 16 days ago, but it just changed on our agents today)

Which appears to rely on: 
grunt-legacy-log@2.0.0 (hooker@0.2.3, colors@1.1.2, grunt-legacy-log-utils@2.0.1, lodash@4.17.10)

With grunt-legacy-log-utils@2.0.1 which appears to rely on chalk, which appears to rely on:
escape-string-regexp (https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-legacy-log-utils/v/2.0.1)

We resolved the build issue by specifying grunt@1.0.2 which uses:

grunt-legacy-log@1.0.2 (hooker@0.2.3, colors@1.1.2, grunt-legacy-log-utils@1.0.0, lodash@4.17.10)

After setting the build back to using grunt <1.0.3 the build started working.  Hope it helps!

Comment: You just specify that in the project’s package.json file? Ours is currently set to “~1.0.1”

Comment: Ha, did exactly that (changed from "~1.0.1" to "1.0.2") and all is well.  Much obliged.