# EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory while writing to a file named 'css'

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm trying to use `fs.writeFile` with options `{ flag: 'w+' }`. When I trying to create a file named **'css'** without a file extension, it gives me an error,

```
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open -path-
```

But, I need to create this **'css'** file in disc.

I tried this in Windows 10 x64, got this error, also in Ubuntu 18.04 too.

What should I do?

http://prntscr.com/m5t3jm

Comment: [This any help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20417119/1377002)

Comment: @Andy , yes, after research for 2 days, I found that but, i need to create a file without an extension. How can I do this?

Comment: If you have a folder called `css` in the folder where you're trying to add the `css` file I don't think you can. It certainly doesn't work for me on Windows.