# SOLVED: `gatsby develop` yields Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, readlink on the .cache folder

Tags: npm, gatsby

**Solution**
My HDD is formatted as exFat which doen'nt seem to support the `readlink` operation.

---

I am trying to set up a **gatsby** page via the **gatsby CLI**. The 'gatsby new' wokrs and set's up everything nicely, as far as I can tell. When it comes to starting the develop server I get the Error like in the title: "Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, readlink './path/on/my/hdd/.cache'
I learned, that "EISDIR means that the target of the operation is a directory in reality but that the expected filetype of the target is something other than a directory." ([Using Node.js I get, "Error: EISDIR, read"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417118/using-node-js-i-get-error-eisdir-read)).
What drives me mad is, that a file called .cache wouldn't make much sense, so somewhere deep down in this gatsby jungle has to be something, that gets messed up.

I've tryed node Versions `10.16.0` and `12.2.0` managed via nvm on windows 10. I've tryed different Folders and Harddrives, I've force cleared my node cache, I've tryed different starter packages, I've tryed npm update on the node_modules installed via gatsby.

```
PS > gatsby develop
success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.075 s
success load plugins - 9.615 s
success onPreInit - 0.003 s
success initialize cache - 0.074 s
```

**ERROR**

> Unable to copy site files to .cache EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, readlink `'C:\my-gatsby-website\.cache'`

Comment: Try deleting the cache folder

Comment: Thank you, @JossClassey. As I said I've force cleared my node cache. The problematic .cache folder gets created via (and used by) the `gatsby develop` command.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42677294/9636451

Comment: I've been having the exact same issue but I found this issue on Github: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/4950 This may give an idea on what to look for but I am still trying to solve it as well. Let me know if you found anything!

Comment: 'gatsby clean' command solved the issue for me.