# Struck on node.js.npm command keeps giving just one output "Error: EISDIR:illegal operation on a directory, read". .npmrc is not found in directory

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-config

I was unable to send e-mail through Node.js. So I googled a few pages.
And I saw a command and executed it.

The command was `npm config set cafile /path/to/your/cert.pem --global`.

Now it ended up giving only one output for all npm commands

> Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

I couldn't find `.npmrc` file anywhere in the parent directory. But I saw one in the project folder and it was empty.

Comment: I hope you learned a lession: Dont run random commands you find on the internet.
Try reinstalling npm or unset the ca file

Comment: I tried uninstalling. Not helped.
How do I unset the ca file.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm/config#cafile & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417118/using-node-js-i-get-error-eisdir-read Did you really execute the comand like that: `npm config set cafile /path/to/your/cert.pem --global` ?

Comment: As in the first link, I can't locate cafile also.
In second link , its related to node.js, not npm.

Yes, I executed the command as it is.

Comment: @Marc
If I use this command `npm config set strict-ssl false --global`, where will this configure?